# Check if ActionPerform method occured but from another class

Tags: java, swing

How to check from a class `ModalDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener`  if `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method ocurred in another class (`Connect extends JFrame implements ActionListener`)? And one step further, how to check which of two buttons that I have in ModalDialog fired ActionPerformed method? (I know about `event.getSource`, but I need to check it from another class).

```
public ModalDialog()
{
    btn8 = new Button("human");
    btn8.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(60,40));
    btn8.addActionListener(this);

    btn9 = new Button("robot");
    btn9.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(60,40));
    btn9.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

}
class Connect extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    ModalDialog md = new ModalDialog();
    if(md.ActionPerformed(e)....)...something like that...
}
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should name your button variables better.

Comment: Isn't there anything like `e.getSource()` in the `ActionEvent` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check from a class ModalDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener if actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

This is a basic problem of how to return information from one class to another.  The simple answer is to provide a getter method, which returns the selected value.

Start by defining the value to be returned, here I used a `enum`, as it clearly defines what could be returned

```
public enum Option {
    HUMAN, ROBOT;
}
```

Update your `ModalDialog` to provide a getter to return the selected value

```
public class ModalDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private Option selection;

    public ModalDialog() {
        setModal(true);
        Button btn8 = new Button("human");
        btn8.addActionListener(this);

        Button btn9 = new Button("robot");
        btn9.addActionListener(this);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(btn8);
        add(btn9);

        pack();
    }

    public Option getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //...
    }
}
```

When the dialog is closed, the caller can now call `getSelection` to get the selected value (or `null` if the user closed the dialog via the <kbd>[X]</kbd> button

> And one step further, how to check which of two buttons that I have in ModalDialog fired ActionPerformed method?

This is not an uncommon problem, and there a number of ways you might implement it.  Since you've already implemented `ActionListener` at the class level, you could just make use of the `actionCommand` support available in buttons, which defaults to the text of the button

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
    switch (cmd) {
        case "human": 
            selection = Option.HUMAN;
            break;
        case "robot": 
            selection = Option.ROBOT;
            break;
    }
    setVisible(false);
}
```

So now, when the dialog is closed, you can just request the selected value...

```
ModalDialog dialog = new ModalDialog();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);

Option selection = dialog.getSelection();
System.out.println("You choose " + selection);
```

Comment: as output I always get robot, whatever I choose(for x i get null)? I have enum inside ModalDialog class, ActionPerformed method which you wrote I put into ModalDialog too, and last part of code is in main.

Comment: Sorry, been writing in Swift, which has a different approach to `switch` statements, check update